# grep in with --include in project with wariable depth

Tags: vim, grep, include

I really like working with grep for it's robust work and customizability.
`:vimgrep` is too slow for me, grep without `--include` (or `--exclude`) too. Also I work with at least 8 file types and `--include` is a huge helper.

My problem is that:

```
:grep "ILookForThat" **/*.{c,h}*
```

Search only one catalog depths, while I need at least four.

```
:grep -R "ILookForThat" --include=*.{c,h}*
```

Doesn't work ( the same with `"*.{c,h}*"` )

What I look for is answer: how to make `grep` (not `vimgrep`, `ag`, or anything else) work, or maybe some answer like: "That definitely should work".

I can add that I use 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , removed my aliases for grep.
Of course answers without quicklist are with no acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:grep -r --include=*.{c,h}*  ILookForThat .` 
Everything works as designed, but grep used from within vim has to have a starting point which is stated with a **dot** character.

Answer (score 2):

After some quick tests I think this should work for you but it's a little verbose:

```
:grep -r --include="*.c" --include="*.h" "ILookForThat" .
```

You could consider wrapping this in a custom `:command` if it's too verbose to be useful.

Comment: It's not recursive and wildcards should still work so there should be no need for splitting. Finally it would be a funny command - as I need that for at least in 5 configurations on 8 filetypes.
I really aperciate your tries and count on you :)

Comment: Ooops, I forgot the -r in my answer.  Updated.